# Using IIS6 as ASP.NET development host in Visual Studio 2008 on Win7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, windows-7, iis-6

I've inherited a ASP.NET 1.1 webapp that runs in production on win2k3 under IIS6. I'd like to closely match this environment during development and testing. For reasons I won't go into, using Cassini/VS Development Server isn't ideal so I'm trying to set up my Visual Studio environment to use IIS6. I do my development on VS 2008 on Win7, and from what I can tell, IIS6 is only supported on Win2k3 and XP Pro x64. Am I stuck using Win7's built-in IIS7?

Comment: I don't know if you can install IIS6 on Windows 7, so I can't really help, but I do know that you can replicate the live environment on a VMWare, or similar, image, and that's probably what I'd do.

Comment: d'oh. i just googled this and found my own question, months later... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use IIS7 but if it is run in classic mode then it will closely emulate the IIS6 way of working. For the differences I wouldn't bother with the overhead of a VM, there aren't enough incompatibilities that I know of to warrant it.